# Does anyone know why my fbx mesh has holes?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting, .fbx

[image]

I have made an animated object using Blender, however, when I export it as an fbx and transfer it to Spark AR, the mesh has large holes in it. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Any chance you have flipped normals/faces? You can check using "face orientation" under overlays.

Comment: Ive tried that and it hasnt worked